# ng-infinite-scroll saying my controller's not a function, got undefined

Tags: angularjs, nginfinitescroll

https://github.com/sroze/ngInfiniteScroll

Okay, so I've loaded the ng-infinite-scroll.min.js

When I load the module, that breaks it

angular.module('myApp', ['infinite-scroll']);

It tells me some controller is now undefined.
Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.25/ng/areq?p0=UserbarController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined

Comment: Can you post your code...? We can't help with just this.

Comment: Sure, not sure what else I should post though? That's literally all I typed and it broke it lol

Comment: Ehh what about your controller definition.. UserbarController?

Comment: That's working fine! It changes from maincontroller to usercontroller to whatever controller's next!

Answer (score 0):

Check your html. Somewhere in your html there's an ng-controller="your_controller" directive and you don't have that controller defined in your javascript files our script tags.